# BasicTeX: how to tlmgr install package from local folder?

Tags: tlmgr

I have BasicTex installed on my MacBook Pro.
I wish to install `emerald` fonts, but if I run

```
sudo tlmgr install emerald
```

I get the following error message:

```
tlmgr: package repository https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package emerald not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

I tried to change repo with

```
sudo tlmgr option repository https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

and tried again `tlmgr install emerald`, but I got the same error message.

Therefore, I downloaded the `emerald` package from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emerald) but I cannot understand how to install it with tlmgr.
I read somewhere that it is enough to copy the emerald folder into `~/texmf` but I don't have such a folder.

If it may be useful, the output of the command `where tlmgr` returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr` whereas `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2022basic/texmf-local`. However, `ls /usr/local/texlive/2022basic` returns

```
LICENSE.CTAN        install-tl      texmf-config        texmf.cnf
LICENSE.TL      install-tl.log      texmf-dist      texmfcnf.lua
bin         release-texlive.txt texmf-var       tlpkg
```

Comment: I think `tlmgr` is not updatable at the minute as it is currently getting ready for the release of TeXlive 2023

Comment: You cannot download a package and install it with tlmgr. That is not possible. If you look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emerald you'll notice that it lists that only MikTeX has `emerald`, texlive does not, presumably because of the licenses. And as such you cannot install `emerald` via `tlmgr` by normal means at least.

Comment: @JamesT `emerad` is not available via texlive. And as far as I know TL22 has not been frozen yet.

Comment: Auch! That is a bad news. I was not aware that MikTeX and TexLive may mismatch in terms of packages. Ok, then I assume that I have to manually move the dowloaded emerald folder somewhere? If so, where? I guess somewhere in /usr/local/texlive/2022basic but where exactly?

Comment: It should go into texmf-local, run `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` to find it. Note that since TeXLive on a Mac is owned by root, you need to remember to use `sudo`

Comment: There is an extra outside repository for `tlmgr` that might contain stuff not available for TeXLive through CTAN. But I don't remember the name. Just found it `tlcontrib`, but `emrald` is not listed there.

Comment: @daleif I am aware of sudo, thanks! :) As you see, I don't have a texmf-local folder, but I installed other fonts (e.g. droid) so I assume that there is another location where I shall copy the folder.

Comment: Then you just create that folder if it is missing. BasicTeX does give a lot of things you have to do by hand.

Comment: I created a `/usr/local/texlive/2022basic/texmf-local` and copied emerald folder there, but it didn't work.